# Foundational Stetches for CrossFit

Tags: flexibility, crossfit, mobility

I feel like there are so many mobility stretches out there for your body, but which ones do you really need to do.

To be an all around CrossFit athlete and have continual gains you must improve your mobility just as much as you weightlift/strength train and perform metcons.

This means you should have good mobility in:

- Wrist
- Shoulder
- Hip
- Ankle

  Am I missing any? By performing these they will aid in performing the following foundation of CrossFit movements:

Overhead Squat, Deadlift, Push Press, Snatch, Clean & Jerk, Push Jerk

I'm trying to find out what series of mobility exercises I should repetitively do in order to aid in the above movements. What's the timeframe and frequency of doing these?